# I am trying to install maven in ubuntu but not able to install properly getting this message

Tags: maven

nautiydp@nautiydp-Aspire-V5-472:~$ mvn -v
The program 'mvn' can be found in the following packages:
 * maven
 * maven2
Try: sudo apt-get install

Comment: This looks like you were trying to _run_ Maven before you even installed it.  Why would try something like that?

Comment: i hand installed again maven through this in command line- sudo apt-get install maven

Comment: now this is the error - nautiydp@nautiydp-Aspire-V5-472:~$ mvn -version
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/java

Comment: Why not [downloading](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) and unpack the bin.tar.gz and put the bin folder into path and that's it.

Comment: but java is defined correctly- nautiydp@nautiydp-Aspire-V5-472:~$ java -version
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)

Comment: @khmarbaise - I have tried that and defined these lines in bashrc- #MAVEN setup
export MAVEN_HOME="BigDataExperiment/apache-maven-3.3.3"
set PATH="$PATH:$MAVEN_HOME/bin"

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I am trying since morning but still not able to setup maven- I had tried both ways- installing maven by this -sudo apt-get install maven and second way downloading and extracting it and defining in bashrc- could you please help me out in this

Comment: Look at the comment from @khmarbaise...it is spot on.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I tried the same which khmarbaise suggested - but still getting this - mvn -version Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly. We cannot execute usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never install Maven with apt-get. The distro people do unpredictable things and the Apache Maven project does not support the results. Just download a tar.gz from maven.apache.org and follow the simple instructions to unpack and use.

Comment: Even I downloaded the tar.gz from  maven.apache.org  and unpacked and used it still giving this error - nautiydp@nautiydp-Aspire-V5-472:~$ mvn -version
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/java

Comment: You need to define your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen- I already defined that-#JAVA HOME DIRECTORY SET UP
export JAVA_HOME="usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_40"
set PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
export PATH

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this now maven is setup-

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_40
export M2_HOME=/usr/lib/maven/apache-maven-3.3.3
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_40/bin:/usr/lib/maven/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin